# Should we store long strings on stack in assembly?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, stack-memory

The general way to store strings in NASM is to use `db` like in `msg: db 'hello world', 0xA`. I think this stores the string in the `bss` section. So the string will occupy the storage for the duration of the entire program. Instead, if we store it in the stack, it will be alive only during the local frame. For small strings (less than 8 bytes), this can be done using `mov dword [rsp], 'foo'`. But for longer strings, the string has to be split and be stored using multiple instructions. So this would increase the executable size (I thought so).

So now, which is better in large programs with multiple strings? Are any of the assumptions I made above, wrong?

Comment: The bss section is for zero-initialising at runtime generally. Initialised data can go into the data section or text section. Or there may be a specific section for read-only data, too. Minor error in your question: Using a single dword write you can only initialise 4 bytes at a time, which is a string of up to 3 bytes if you want a zero terminator byte included.

Comment: Related re: efficiency of constructing strings on the stack (although in 32-bit mode): [Re-use string at known address to save bytes and reduce size of shellcode payload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57469740)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mov dword [rsp] 'foo'` assembles to `C70424666F6F00`, it takes 7 bytes to encode 4 payload characters.
In comparison with standard static way `DB 'foo',0` the definition of string as immediate operand in code section increases the code size by 75 %.

Your dynamic method may be profitable only if you could eliminate the **.rodata** or **.data** section entirely (which is seldom the case of large programs). Each additional section takes more space in executable program than its netto contents because of its file-alignment (in PE format it is 512 bytes).
And even when your program has no other static data in data sections beside long strings, you could spare more space with static declaration in **.text** (code) section.

Comment: `mov rcx, imm64` + `push rcx` is 10+1 = 11 total bytes for 8 bytes of payload  = 73% efficiency, vs. 4/7 = 57%.  (At an offset from RSP it would be even worse, but to save code size you could use RBP+imm8 instead of RSP+imm8, but that's still 4 bytes per 7.  You could mix `push imm32` with `mov dword [rsp+4], imm32` but that's also bad.)

Comment: Compilers will sometimes use immediate data to init a local struct or array that *has* to be on the stack anyway (i.e. they have to pass a non-const pointer to another function); their threshold for switching to copying from .rodata (with movdqa xmm load/store) is higher than 8 bytes.  But when you just want to print the string, you just need to pass a pointer to .rodata without copying it to the stack at all, so the threshold is much lower for it to be worth it to use stack space.  Maybe 8 bytes, maybe 16, maybe only 4, depending on I-cache vs. D-cache pressure in your program.

Comment: Of course, for just 4 bytes you'd use `push 'foo'` = 5 bytes = 80% efficiency.  Getting the pointer into a register with `mov rdi, rsp` is smaller than `lea rdi, [rel msg_foo]` by 4 bytes, so it's an overall win for total size (unless padding for function alignment bumps it up or hides it).  But anyway, comparing against the *best* option instead of the worst might be a good idea for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> But for longer strings string has to be split and be stored using multiple instructions. So this would increase the executable size (I thought so).

Yep, and in almost all cases, the number of bytes used by those instructions will exceed the number of bytes that would be needed to just store the string in memory normally.  (The instruction includes all the bytes of the immediate, with a few exceptions like zero- and sign-extension, as well as additional bytes to encode the opcode, destination address, etc).  And code, of course, also occupies (virtual) memory for the entire duration of the program.  There's no free lunch.

As such, you should just assemble the strings directly into memory with `db` as you have done.  But try to arrange for them to go in a read-only section such as `.text` or `.rodata` depending on what your system supports.  A modern operating system will then be able to discard those pages from physical memory if there is memory pressure, knowing that they can be reloaded from the executable if needed again.  This is entirely transparent to your program.  If there are many strings that will be needed at the same times, you can optimize a little by trying to arrange for them to be adjacent in your program's memory (defining them all together in one asm file should suffice).

You could also design something where at runtime, you read your strings from an external file into dynamically allocated memory, then free it when done with them.  This was a common technique for programs on ancient operating systems with limited physical memory and no virtual memory support (think MS-DOS).

Answer (score 3):

The string data has to be *somewhere*.  Existing as immediates in your machine code takes space in the `.text` section of your program, normally linked into the same program segment as `.rodata` where you'd keep string literals.  Running instructions to store strings to the stack means the data has to come into I-cache, then go out into D-cache.

But for long *redundant* strings, code to generate them in memory may be smaller than the string itself.  This comes down to the **[Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)**; minimum size of a program that can output (or generate in an array) the given data.  That program could be a gzip or zstd decompressor with some input constant data, could be good for a very large string or set of strings, much larger than the decompression code.  Or for a *specific* case, have a look at code-golf questions like *The alphabet in programming languages* where [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/194014#194014) is 9 bytes of x86 machine code (including a `ret`) which inefficiently stores 1 byte at a time, incrementing a pointer in a loop, to produce the 26-byte string (without a terminating 0).  Slow but compact.

---

#### Pushing / Storing from immediates

For just 4 bytes (not including the 0 terminator) you'd use `push 'foo'` = 5 bytes = 80% efficiency.  On x86-64, that's a qword push (sign-extending the imm32 to 64-bit), so we get 4 bytes of zeros for free.

After that, getting the pointer into a register with `mov rdi, rsp` (3 bytes) is 4 bytes smaller than `lea rdi, [rel msg_foo]` (7 bytes), so it's an overall win for total size (unless padding for function alignment bumps it up or hides it).  But anyway, comparing against the *best* option instead of the worst might be a good idea for your answer.

Compilers will sometimes use immediate data to init a local struct or array that *has* to be on the stack anyway (i.e. they have to pass a non-const pointer to another function); their threshold for switching to copying from `.rodata` (with `movdqa xmm` load/store) is higher than 8 bytes.  But when you just want to print the string, you just need to pass a pointer to `.rodata` without copying it to the stack at all, so the threshold is much lower for it to be worth it to use stack space.  Maybe 8 bytes, maybe 16, maybe only 4, depending on I-cache vs. D-cache pressure in your program.

### For short but not tiny strings

`mov rcx, imm64` + `push rcx` is 10+1 = 11 total bytes for 8 bytes of payload = 73% efficiency, vs. 4/7 = 57%. (At an offset from RSP it would be even worse, but to save code size you could use RBP+imm8 instead of RSP+imm8, but that's still 4 bytes per 7. You could mix `push sign_extended_imm32` with `mov dword [rsp+4], imm32` but that's also bad.)

This does have overhead that scales with string size, so it quickly becomes more size-efficient to just copy from `.rodata`, e.g. with an XMM loop, `call memcpy`, or even `rep movsb` if you're optimizing for size.

Or of course just using the string in `.rodata` if possible, if you don't *need* to make a copy you can modify on the stack.

---

**Shellcode is a common use-case for techniques like this.**  You need a single "flat" sequence of bytes, usually not containing any `00` bytes which would terminate a C string.

You can have some data past the end of the actual machine code part, and `mov` store some zeros into that and generate pointers to it, but that's somewhat cumbersome.  And you need a position-independent way to get pointers into registers.  call/pop works, if you jump forward and call backward so the rel32 doesn't involve any 00 bytes.  Same for RIP-relative lea.

It's often just as easy to push a zeroed register, or an imm8 or imm32, and get some zeros into memory along with ASCII data that way.  Generating it a bit at a time makes it easy to `mov rsi, rsp` or whatever, instead of needing position-independent addressing relative to RIP.

Comment: (I probably had this answer half-written for over a year.  I forget if I was going to say more or make some examples. :/)

Comment: `Kolmogorov complexity` is interesting. Have to read more about that.