# Getting absolute address of data in shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, memory-address, shellcode

Here's my shellcode:

```
    xor rax, rax
    xor rdi, rdi
    xor rsi, rsi
    xor rdx, rdx

    ; getting address of `pathname`
    mov rdi, [something]
    mov al, 59
    mov rdi, rsp
    syscall

    xor rax,rax
    mov al, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

_pathname:
    db "/usr/bin/shutdown",0
```

Simple `execve` and exit, that's all. The problem is that I can't get the absolute address in order to access *pathname*. The "solution" to this, that I have found, is rigging the code something like this:

```
call _end

_start:
    pop rdi ; absolute address of _start
    ; then add bytes to get to address of _end

_end:
    call start
    db "/usr/bin/shutdown", 0
```

This never made sense to me, and it didn't work. I also tried using FPU instructions, which were supposed to work as well, but they didn't work either.

Anybody have a solution?

OS: Linux
Architecture: amd64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86-64 you have RIP-relative addressing modes, so you should be able to simply do `lea rdi, [rel _pathname]`.  The assembler computes the displacement between the address of the current instruction (or actually the next one) and the label `_pathname`, and encodes it into the instruction.  At runtime this displacement is added to `rip` and the result placed in `rdi`.

x86-32 doesn't have relative addressing modes, so in 32-bit mode, your `call/pop` trick is the standard way to accomplish this, despite being awkward.  And it does work in 64-bit mode too. But the address popped by `pop rdi` isn't the address of `_start`; rather it's the return address pushed by the `call _start` instruction, i.e. the address of the byte following the `call _start` instruction.  In this case it is exactly the first byte of your `/usr/bin/shutdown` string, so in fact you wouldn't have to add anything.

Note that you are passing a null pointer as the `argv` and `envp` arguments to `execve`.  This is legal for the kernel, but the `shutdown` program is probably not expecting this and it may crash upon startup.  So you might have to do some more work to construct a minimal argument vector with `argv[0] == "shutdown"` at least.

Comment: Note that shellcode needs to be free of `00` bytes, so `[RIP+rel32]` is only usable with negative displacements (or with some large constant added that you subtract from the final address, like `lea rdi, [rel foo + 0x01010101]` / `sub rdi, 0x01010101` as in [Avoiding 0xFF bytes in shellcode using CALL to read RIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55783375))  Without trickery, this means your code has to be after the string so you need to `jmp` over it, and it can't have a terminating 0.

Comment: The jmp/call/pop trick is more compact, and the backwards `call` makes the rel32 negative.  (The OP used `call _end` instead of `jmp _end` which breaks this trick because there's no `call rel8`; the forward `call` will have zeros in the `call rel32` encoding.)

Comment: @NateEldredge `execve("\1", NULL, NULL) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` from `strace` when using `lea rdi, [rel _pathname + 0x69696969]` and `sub rdi, 0x69696969`. Any more wisdom?

Comment: @R-Rothrock: It works for me.  You did remember to remove the `mov rdi, rsp` right?  Otherwise please post a [mcve] of the code you are testing.

Comment: @R-Rothrock: `"\1"` as the path could be the result of doing `mov rdi, rsp` while RSP was still pointing to `argc` (which it does in the Linux process-startup state.)
BTW, `_start` is a very bad choice of label name if you're going to put code ahead of it.  If you did `global _start`, the linker would set the process entry point to `_start`, so execution would start there, instead of at the top of the text section (`ld`'s default if there's no exported `_start` symbol.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I know, I didn't paste the whole file. And yes. I forgot to remove the `mov rdi, rsp` line. Many thanks.